# Ethernet not active after migration from CentOS 7 to Oracle Linux

Tags: migration, centos7, oraclelinux

I've just finished migrating a workstation to Oracle Linux from CentOS 7 using the centos2ol.sh script by strictly following the instructions in https://docs.oracle.com/en/learn/switch_centos7_ol7/index.html#download-and-run-centos2ol-script

After rebooting the machine, it lost network connection, even if the Ethernet adapter is set to start on boot.

By running nmtui, I can see and edit the Ethernet adapater info, but I cannot activate it (it does not appear in the list of adapters that can be activated). The same with nmcli.